# Creating an ExtJS pop-up form?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

does anyone know how to create a simple ExtJS 'pop-up form', meaning the user selects something on a menu, a pop-up appears on the screen to ask some input from the user, and finally the information is submitted.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap a form panel inside of an ext window. That's the easiest way to do it.